# How can I correctly retrieve the request JSON payload inside this .NET controller method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have this controller method handling a **POST** request:

```
[SharePointContextWebAPIFilter]
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("InviaMailAlProtocollo")]
public IHttpActionResult InviaMailAlProtocollo(string siglaIdUor)
{

    Console.WriteLine("INTO InviaMailAlProtocollo()" + siglaIdUor);

    Console.WriteLine("INTO InviaAlProtocollo()" + siglaIdUor);

    string requestContent = Request.Content.ToString();


    return Ok("TEST");

}
```

I am performing a **POST** request passing a JSON document inside the body of the request.

How can I correctly retrieve and print this JSON document inside my controller method?

Comment: so how your output will be look?

Answer (score 1):

First To need To Declare A Data transfer object(DTO) [Details Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) 
In your model Folder that looks the same as the json object.

Forexmaple you have a json object looks like this:

{
Id:22,
Name:"Ibrahim",
Children:["Name1","Name2","Name3"] 
}

make a corresponding plain old Csharp object(Poco) 
like the following:

```
  public class ParentBasicInfo
    { 
    public int Id {get ;set;}
    public string Name{get ;set;}
    public List<string>Children{get ;set;}
    }
```

in your controller put an instance of your poco:

Replace:

```
public IHttpActionResult InviaMailAlProtocollo(string siglaIdUor)
{
}
```

with :

```
public IHttpActionResult InviaMailAlProtocollo(ParentBasicInfo siglaIdUor)
{
}
```

all of the json object will be inslide of siglaIdUor

you can access its properties like any object.

Hope that Helps.